# flash video streaming on android

Tags: android, flash

I want to play a flash video streaming on Android. Is there a way to achieve this since flash is not supported on Android anymore starting version 4.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Try [vGet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mb.videoget&hl=en). It allows to play flash videos on many sites.